# NSMutableString does not listed in autoreleasepool by _CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools()

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, nsmutablestring

With ARC enabled(XCode 4.3.2, iOS 4.0), [_CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) does not print the address of **token** in any pools. I checked that **token** is released as expected after the pool ends, so there is no issue but something goes behind scenes. I suspect that it may be something related to objc_autoreleaseReturnValue.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableString *token = [NSMutableString string];
    // When following line uncommented, 
    // **token** is listed in autorelease pool by _CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools.
    //[token appendFormat:@"%@", @"xyz"];

    NSLog(@"%@", token);

}
```

So, is not _CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools() reliable? How could **token** be autoreleased although not listed in any autorelease pool?

**Edit:** As i finally find out the reason and determined that it's already been listed, the appendFormat must not work different. It seems that while calling appendFormat, memory addresses were in the ([1..F]XXX XXXX) range so _CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools lists those addresses exactly and i could find the address when i searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been bitten by left-most excessive zeroes in memory address. I was directly copying and searching the address returned for the token. NSMutableString instance actually appears as __NSCFString in the list returned by _CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools().

```
(lldb) po token
(NSMutableString *) $1 = 0x[-->0<--]898e690

(lldb) po (NSString *)_CFAutoreleasePoolPrintPools()
...    
objc[731]: [0x82dc1a8]  ################  POOL 0x82dc1a8
objc[731]: [0x82dc1ac]         0x898e690  __NSCFString
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the magic of objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue. If the autoreleased object is going to be immediately retained by the caller then it is not autoreleased - so it would not show up in the autorelease pool. I brought up the assembly assistant window and see the call to objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue just after the call to obj_msgSend for the [NSMutableString string] call.

See [this blog post](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/) for more information. It references comments in [Apple code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-arr.mm) that says:

> objc_autoreleaseReturnValue() examines the caller's instructions
>   following   the return. If the caller's instructions immediately call 
>   objc_autoreleaseReturnValue, then the callee omits the -autorelease
>   and saves   the result in thread-local storage. If the caller does not
>   look like it   cooperates, then the callee calls -autorelease as
>   usual.
>
> objc_autoreleaseReturnValue checks if the returned value is the same
>   as the   one in thread-local storage. If it is, the value is used
>   directly. If not,   the value is assumed to be truly autoreleased and
>   is retained again.  In   either case, the caller now has a retained
>   reference to the value.
>
> Tagged pointer objects do participate in the fast autorelease
>   scheme,    because it saves message sends. They are not entered in the
>   autorelease    pool in the slow case.

Comment: I forgot to mention that retainCount is incremented by objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue() and retainCount is 2 after string is created by string method. I think [NSMutableString string] returns an autoreleased string so objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue() retains it.